# How to achieve multiple independent sessions into a Raspbian Pi3

Tags: raspbian, ssh, rdp, openssh, gnuplot

I have a certain Pi3 OUTSIDE that is collecting multiple data values at specific intervals.  From that data set it is possible to generate various types of plots in gnuplot.

I would like to be able to connect into it multiple times in order to have several live plots running at once.

The live plotting is the easy part.

[How can you watch gnuplot realtime data plots as a live graph, with automatic updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470965/how-can-you-watch-gnuplot-realtime-data-plots-as-a-live-graph-with-automatic-up/44471008#44471008)

EXCERPT:

> Each gnuplot program is using these two commands at the end so the
>   plots update as new data comes in:
>
> ```
> pause 24
> reread
> ```
>
> 24 is arbitrary, since the data comes in every 120 seconds.  Seemed
>   prudent to try to avoid collisions.

I have tried using Windows Remote Desktop.

First thing to do is edit /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini file so login screen prompts for the port number,  with a default of 5910.

The first time I connect I must backspace over it and input a -1 at login, of course.  If I disconnect I can always log back in with port 5910 and find that session still running.

My /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini includes this:

```
[xrdp1]
name-sesman-Xvnc
lib-livnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=ask5910
```

So first login after a reboot you change it to a -1.
Then if you get disconnected you can leave it as 5910 and it will reconnect to your existing virtual session.

To achieve a second virtual session I have tried logging in and changing the port to 5911 the second time, and 5912.  But each time it says problem connecting.

> When I connect in using 5910 from a second PC it is the same virtual
>   session so if I move a window it happens on both screens.

So, having tried RDP enough to know it isn't the answer, the question stands.

Can I achieve multiple independent sessions into a Raspbian Pi3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is YES.

Instead o fusing RDP, there is a much better way to achieve this, as spelled out in the answer to this question:

[How can I set up my G-Mouse USB GPS for use with Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68816/how-can-i-set-up-my-g-mouse-usb-gps-for-use-with-raspbian)

EXCERPT (with edits to make it applicable to this answer):

> If you want to run a remote graphical program remotely from another
>   Linux machine(s) use these two commands together:
>
> ```
> ssh -Y pi@OUTSIDE
> gnuplot
> ```
>
> The -Y is there to allow SSH to carry the X-11 output over ssh.

*Scenario:  I want to connect to my outdoor system which controls the solar tracker thaat moves the 3 sets of 2 100W panels to follow the sun.  More importantly, it is being ventilated to keep the temperatures in a reasonable range for the electronics.  It has a separate fixed 50W panel to keep a separate battery charged out there.  It also measures the all-sky light intensity and an anemometer for wind speed.  This is all accomplished with a combination of a Rpi3B with external antenna, connected by serial to an Arduino Nano that takes the reasings and prints them to seria where the Rpi has a program waiting to receive all the data, add a date and time stamp and write it to a data file.  All readings are taken at 120-sec intervals, and all data is written into a tab-delimited CSV file which gnuplot can read with ease.*

Here is the sequence to get three live plots from the same system:

```
Open terminal window
ssh -Y OUTSIDE
gnuplot
load "plt4    <--loads the data showing 4 temperature sensors

Open terminal window
ssh -Y OUTSIDE
gnuplot
load "pl12

Open terminal window
ssh -Y OUTSIDE
gnuplot
load "plux
```

Once the plots are running I resize the terminal windows and arrange them on the screen.

For good measure I do another terminal showing the ssh sequence.

**Voila, here I have four independent sessions into the OUTSIDE system with three of them displaying live plots and the fourth one to show hostname before and after the ssh command**:

[image]

That is the answer.

---

**Background on why the ssh command worked so easily:**

OpenSSH-server is loaded on both systems:

```
sudo aptitude install openssh-server
```

On the ALARMS system I ran these commands, ONCE:

```
cd
ssh-keygen       (Press enter to the 4 prompts)
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub OUTSIDE      
(enter your password for OUTSIDE)
(It will then prompt you to try ssh to make sure it worked)
```

---

**This can also be done in Windows with the PuTTY PSSH program.**

First, I put C:\windows\Program Files (x86)/putty in my path using environment variables in the system configuration, advanced screen.

```
pssh pi@OUTSIDE
```

will do the same as ssh does in Linux.

For it to carry X-11 sessions takes some configuration.  *I know it works but haven't tested it yet*

[How to make Putty do the equivalent of “ssh -X”?](https://superuser.com/questions/299158/how-to-make-putty-do-the-equivalent-of-ssh-x)

EXCERPT:

> @baraboom's answer: You can enable X11 Forwarding in Putty's
>   configuration. In the menu on the left, find the Connection tree. In
>   SSH, expand it and you will see Tunnels window. Click "Enable X11
>   forwarding". It is setting the default to X display at "localhost:0".

Comment: Using xrdp, I am not aware of anything. However: are you limited to using rdp for some reason?

Comment: Try opening a single ssh session with X forwarding enabled, then entering each of the 3 commands followed by '&' to run as a background task.

Comment: You hit the nail right on the head, @bobstro.  Oncew I took off my blinders I could see SSH and how I had used it for X-11 output when I was installing my GPS.  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68816/how-can-i-set-up-my-g-mouse-usb-gps-for-use-with-raspbian  +2